# How do I dynamically run a React Native app inside another React Native app?

Tags: react-native

Can it be done besides basic integration of code? Ideally, a RN app should be able to dynamically download the bundle of a nested app from the server. Then it should execute the bundle inside some kind of customized root in the view. It should also have a basic life cycle control over the nested app. Is it technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/).

The root component of your application have to be wrapped into codePush's higher-order component:

```
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

class MyApp extends Component {
}

MyApp = codePush(MyApp);
```

Then you can release js bundle updates any time from the cli:

```
code-push release-react <appName> <platform>
```